# How to display HTML widgeds in line

Tags: html, widget, inline

I'm trying to display four Social Media HTML Widgets in line on my website.
I tried a few codes but none worked. Can you please give me some advice?

Here's my code:

https://www.link3.com' target='_center' title='Title1'>https://www.source3.com'
style='border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;' alt="" />https://www.link4.com' target='_center' title='Title1'>https://www.source4.com'
style='border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;' alt="" />

Comment: <div align="right"><a href='https://www.link1.com' target='_center' title='Title1'><img src='https://www.source1.com'
style='border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;' alt="" /></a></div>
<div align="right"><a href='https://www.link2.com' target='_center' title='Title1'><img src='https://www.source2.com'
style='border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;' alt="" /></a></div>
<div align="right"><a href='https://www.link3.com' target='_center' title='Title1'><img src='https://www.source3.com'
style='border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;' alt="" /></a></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS, either inline, like below, or in stylesheets etc.

Try using `display: inline-block;`

```
<div style="display:inline-block;border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;">
  https://www.source1.com
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;">
  https://www.source2.com
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;">
  https://www.source3.com
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;">
  https://www.source4.com
</div>
```

Take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

You could also use floats: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

```
<div style="float:left;border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;">
  https://www.source4.com
</div>
```

```css
div {
  background:black;
  width:234px;
  max-width:234px;
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  https://www.source1.com
</div>

<div>
  https://www.source2.com
</div>

<div>
  https://www.source3.com
</div>

<div>
  https://www.source4.com
</div>
```

```
<div style="display:inline-block;border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;">
    <a href='link1.com' target='_center' title='Title1'>
      <img src='source1.com' style='border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;' alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;">
    <a href='link2.com' target='_center' title='Title1'>
      <img src='source2.com' style='border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;' alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;">
    <a href='link3.com' target='_center' title='Title1'>
      <img src='source3.com' style='border:none;max-width:234px;width:234px;' alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This code is incomplete. My code is in the comment section. Can you please add your code into mine because I don't know where to add it. I've tried different options but it always just shows the elements stacked.

Comment: That's no problem, but mark me as the answer if it was right!

Comment: No problem @Niclas, glad to have been able to help you :)